# How to copy data from a row if a certain value is present in column, using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I've been working on a spreadsheet to help with reporting and I'm stumped on the final element. Essentially, if column G of a worksheet contains a certain text string, I want to copy the appropriate row to another worksheet under the existing data in that sheet.

After two hours of googling I've tried various solutions but haven't been able to configure one to do what I want it to. Currently I'm working with the below:

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim Thisvalue As String
Dim NextRow As Range

Sheets("Week 4").Select
' Find the last row of data
FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
' Loop through each row
For x = 2 To FinalRow
    ' Decide if to copy based on column D
    Thisvalue = Cells(x, 7).Value
    If Thisvalue = "Customer placed on hold" Then
        Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, 33).Copy
        Sheets("Retained data").Select
        NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Cells(NextRow, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Week 4").Select
    End If
Next x
End Sub
```

However, I think I'm on the wrong track and in all honesty I've forgotten so much about VBA that I'm essentially starting from scratch again as far as my knowledge goes. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will loop throug all cells in Column G (until `FinalRow`), and check for value "Customer placed on hold". When it finds, it copies the entire row to the next avaialble row at "Retained data" worksheet.

Note: it's better to avoid using `Select` and `ActiveSheet` as they might change according to your current `ActiveSheet`. Instead it's better to use referenced Sheet objects, `.Cells` and Ranges.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyRow()

Dim x As Long
Dim Thisvalue As String
Dim NextRow As Long
Dim FinalRow As Long

With Sheets("Week 4")    
    ' Find the last row of data in Column A
    FinalRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Loop through each row
    For x = 2 To FinalRow

        ' Decide if to copy based on column G
        If .Cells(x, 7).Value = "Customer placed on hold" Then
             ' Find the last row of data
            NextRow = Sheets("Retained data").Cells(Sheets("Retained data").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            ' copy > paste in 1 line
            .Cells(x, 7).EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Retained data").Range("A" & NextRow + 1)
        End If
    Next x    
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, it's working great now!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Sub Makro2()
Dim x As Integer
Dim Thisvalue As String

Sheets("Week 4").Select
' Find the last row of data
FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
' Loop through each row
For x = 2 To FinalRow
    ' Decide if to copy based on column D
    Thisvalue = Cells(x, 7).Value
    If Thisvalue = "Customer placed on hold" Then
        Range(Cells(x, 1), Cells(x, 33)).Copy
        With Sheets("Retained data")
            .Cells(.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        End With
    End If
Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

since you want to check column "G" values against a string (`"Customer placed on hold"`) then you want to avoid looping through column "A" cells and loop through "string" cells of columns "G" only

then you can avoid looping through all cells and just `Find()` the wanted ones:

```
Sub CopyRow()
    Dim firstAddress As String
    Dim f As Range

    With Worksheets("Week 4") '<--| reference your relevant worksheet
        With .Range("G2", .Cells(.Rows.COUNT, "G").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues) '<--| loop through its column G "string" values only
            Set f = .Find(what:="Customer placed on hold", lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, after:=.Areas(.Areas.COUNT).Cells(.Areas(.Areas.COUNT).COUNT)) '<--| search for wanted string in referenced range, starting from the cell after its last cell (i.e.: the first cell)
            If Not f Is Nothing Then '<--| if found
                firstAddress = f.Address '<--| store its address to stop 'Find()' loop at its wrapping back to the first found cell
                Do
                    With Worksheets("Retained data") '<--| reference target sheet
                        f.EntireRow.Copy .Cells(.Rows.COUNT, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) '<--| copy found cell entire row into last referenced worksheet first not empty cell
                    End With
                    Set f = .FindNext(f) '<--| find next cell matching wanted value
                Loop While f.Address <> firstAddress '<--| exit loop when it wraps back to first found cell
            End If
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

should your column "G" data extend beyond actual range of column "A" data, and you be interested in limiting the range to this latter, then you just have to change:

```
With .Range("G2", .Cells(.Rows.COUNT, "G").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues) '<--| loop through its column G "string" values only
```

to

```
With Intersect(.Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.COUNT, "A").End(xlUp)).EntireRow, .Range("G2", .Cells(.Rows.COUNT, "G").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)) '<--| loop through its column G "string" values only down to its column "A" last not empty row
```